# How do I install a .bin archive on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation

I have read many answers on Ask Ubuntu but I still cannot install genymotion on my Ubuntu. I want to install the following archive I have in my desktop:

```
genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin
```

Comment: Burn it to a disk? Or an USB?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit:

https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Installation.htm

and it'll give you all the details about how to install. Also know that it needs Oracle VirtualBox and DKMS to operate.

Comment: Perhaps giving him an answer as to how to do it stepwise  or a link where steps are mentioned would be beter

Comment: The link that I left does list the steps required to install the software. I don't need to repeat the lengthy details manually here.